# UITableView - UIRefreshControl with Background Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've implemented a UIRefreshControl into as part of a refresh control on a UITableViewController - all appears to work fine as in - if you pull down the page pulls back the data - but I noticed that the activity indicator doesn't appear in the view.

After a bit of investigation I realised that the issue appears to be with a background image I'm applying to the UiTableViewController - If I disable this the activity indicator appears as expected.

My setup is as follows - I have extended a UITableViewController class to create a new class called BG_Blur_TableViewController - This class basically applys a background image via teh following code -

**BG_Blur_TableViewController.m**
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

```
     self.prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:[self.prefs stringForKey:@"BGImageBlur"]]];



}
```

I then use this class in my UITableViewController as follows -

**Article_HP_TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BG_Blur_TableViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"

    @interface Article_HP_TableViewController :      BG_Blur_TableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

    @property NSArray *articleArray;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
     @property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

 @end
```

I apply the refresh control in this method -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
     //self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50);


    // Initialize Refresh Control
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    // Configure Refresh Control
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Configure View Controller
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
```

and remove it with this -

```
- (void)refresh:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Refreshing");

    // End Refreshing
    [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Is there anyway I can apply the refresh control so it appears on top of the bgimage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change `zPosition` of refresh control. You should receive something like:

```
_refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[_ tableView setRefreshControl:_refreshControl];
_refreshControl.layer.zPosition += 1;
```

Comment: Thought this was gonna be a big problem. Thank you